# Web role / worker role / VM role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-web-roles

Sorry for ambiguous question title! I have an asp.net app which works with an additional third party software(burning glass- connects to web app via tcp/ip, requires - properly configured dns entry, fixed ip and minimum of 8gb ram and it is completely managed via command prompt) in a single dedicated server.

I want to convert my web form app to MVC and deploy it in azure and also move the third party software I use( with above requirements). Is it possible to achieve the above requirements in azure?

Which role should I use for burning glass?

Comment: Windows Azure does not currently support a Fixed IP. This may be a blocker.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Burning Glass software app?

Comment: @Brent - once deployed, the IP address remains fixed unless the app is deleted and redeployed. With the latest updates, you can now upgrade role size, add/remove roles, add/remove endpoints all without delete+redeploy.

Comment: I know David, but is the license is bound to the IP. He's still sunk until we have a truely fixed IP :P

Answer (score 3):

The general rule is to install 3rd-party software in a Web or Worker role, alongside your web app if you'd like, as long as:

- You can install via MSI or some other mechanism that doesn't require manual intervention
- The installation time is relatively quick (maybe max. 5 minutes or so)
- The installation is reliable

If any of those are not possible, you'd need to go with a VM Role to pre-install the app.

As far as managing an app via command-line: As long as you can make the command-line calls via your app, you're ok. If you need to enter commands into a console, then that's not practical in Windows Azure unless you can connect to the console remotely. Not knowing about Burning Glass, I don't have any idea whether this can be done.

While Windows Azure doesn't let you select your IP address, the assigned IP address remains in effect as long as you don't delete and redeploy your app. You can upgrade the app without redeploying, so that shouldn't be an issue for you.